Datastream - AWS to GCP
I been trying to connect two cloud providers AWS and GCP and found this documentation

Create an HA VPN gateway to a peer VPN gateway
I already config and set it up. And the result was good, connection both instances are pinging.
Now, I’m trying to stream my database in aws to GCP ( BigQuery ) and I found this example,
Introduction to Datastream for BigQuery on the 2:31 of the video, I saw that he created a profile that connected to the AWS and this is the part I stuck,
Question is do you have guys an example how to connect it? I’m trying to setup AWS RDS MYSQL?
I appreciate your help.
Tried to setup and config and also the VPC Peering of GCP.


create private connectivity  with proper configuration
create AWS RDS MYSQL with private connectivity(VPC Peering )

as per your query, you have already created AWS VPC to your GCP VPC connection using HA VPN, so follow below steps

check/validate that from your GCP's VPC, you are able to connect your AWS RDS MySQL
now create a Private connectivity in DataStream  to your GCP's VPC , which has AWS VPC access via HA VPN

so your datascream source to datastream connectivity is
AWS RDS AWS  ->  HA via VPN -> GCP VPC  -> private connectivity -> DataStream
3)now in your connection profile use connectivity method = private connectivity

other things are already explained in video, so follow that
in your update comment you said that you are using  RDS cluster hostname. but that can not be resolved by datastreamer
so better use IP of your cluster.
you can find  your  RDS cluster private ip from GCP by running following cmd  from your GCP VPC
dig my_example_db.cluster-xxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com

after that use this ip in profile and validate.
once it is working , you also have to make sure that  your RDS private ip is always remain updated in datastreamer profile
So make a GCP scrip ( in small GCP VM instance in same VPC with cron)
e.g.
import socket
import time
import boto3  # Assuming you're using AWS SDK

rds_endpoint = 'my_example_db.cluster-xxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
datastream_client = boto3.client('datastream')
# Replace with the actual ID of your Datastream connection profile
connection_profile_id = 'your_connection_profile_id' 

def update_datastream_profile(new_ip):
    datastream_client.update_connection_profile(
        ConnectionProfileId=connection_profile_id,
        PrivateConnectivity={ 
            'PrivateIpAddress': new_ip 
        }
    )

while True:
    try:
        new_ip = socket.gethostbyname(rds_endpoint)
        update_datastream_profile(new_ip)
        print(f"Datastream profile updated with IP: {new_ip}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error resolving RDS endpoint or updating profile: {e}")
    time.sleep(300)  # Adjust check interval as needed


Hello,
I so confuse on that configuration because I already created that VPC Peering.
I got this error
Test failed
We timed out trying to connect to the data source. Make sure that the hostname and port configuration is correct, and that the data source is available.
first, how can I check/validate that from your GCP's VPC, you are able to connect your AWS RDS MySQL?
I tried checking on the gcp vm like this
mysql -h AWS_RDS_ENDPOINT -u USER -p PASSWORD
and I cant connect.

AWS_RDS_ENDPOINT  is ip (  is it private IP?)  or hostname ?

the RDS_ENDPOINT is like on the video,
but mine is like this, im using cluster.
my_example_db.cluster-xxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
do you have example on "Connection profiles"?

so prefer private IP instead of  hostname

yup. I just follow the instructions on the video but im using the aurora mysql endpoint/hostname.

Trying to ping the IP and still cant connect.

DataStream "private connectivity" will create a subnet in your GCP's VPC, so make sure that from that from that subnet ( ip range provide during  private connectivity )  your  AWS's  private IP is reachable.

and  do this
AWS: Ensure routes for the GCP subnets are propagated to the VPC route table.
GCP: Ensure routes for the AWS subnets are propagated in the Cloud Router.
in AWS
Virtual Private Gateway (VGW), there's an option to enable "Propagate to Route Tables".
Enabling this automatically adds routes learned via BGP over the VPN connection to any route tables associated with the VGW's VPC.
at GCP
BGP Peering: When you establish BGP peering between your HA VPN gateway and the Cloud Router, routes should be exchanged dynamically.

Got this. but I'll give a little architecture on my vpc. since the practice for db is using a private subnet, I also use aws NAT gateway and I have 2 route table in my aws, one main and for private with NAT.... is this another set up for GCP? since I still cant connect the profile?

if  you are using  NAT , is  VM in GCP's VPC able to ping your  database  with private IP ?

Hello divyang4481,
I'm able to ping now vice versa ( public and private subnet )
now I tried again the Datastream with connection profile but still can't connect while I run a test.
Do you have any idea on reverse proxy? or that your script already? if yes how can I deploy that code.

as I said ,  in  subnet of  GCP, are your able to ping your  database cluster  ?
